# Can no longer log into Joomla 3.x backend after removing JoomProject

Tags: login

After following JoomBoost's instructions for removing JoomProject, I can no longer log in to the website's backend, including the main administrator's account.  The Web site's frontend is still working.  All user accounts are nonfunctional.  I have access to the backend database tables.  Can anyone suggest a way to correct the problem?

Tried:
I started by following JoomBoost's instructions, which can be found at https://www.joomboost.com/support/documentation/59-joomproject/the-basics/118-uninstall.html .  I uninstalled only the JoomProject module.  After removing that module, I disabled/deactivated all of the modules having the author "JoomProject" (I think that was it.), and there were many.  That's when I discovered it was no longer possible to log back in to the backend.

I then followed the Joomla instructions "How do you recover or reset your admin password?", which are found at https://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_recover_or_reset_your_admin_password%3F .  I've tried methods 1 and 2 with no success.

---

New Information (Mon Nov  7 17:07:20 UTC 2022)

When trying to log in with the administrator's user ID and (**CORRECT**) password, Joomla seems to process the information, then return an empty log-in box.  Nothing is added to the file ./error_log.  Nothing is added to the file ./logs/error.php.

When trying to log in with the administrator's user ID and (**INCORRECT**) password, Joomla seems to process the information, then return an empty log-in box with the message "Warning
Username and password do not match or you do not have an account yet" at the top.  Nothing is added to the file ./error_log.  The file ./logs/error.php, has the message "joomlafailure Username and password do not match or you do not have an account yet. ("administratorID")" appended.

It appears the authentication process is working and differentiates between the correct and incorrect passwords.  Still can not log in.

Comment: Are you presented with the Administrator Login box/fields or do you get a white page or some other messages?

Comment: What happens if you re-enable the extensions you previously disabled?

Comment: Could you switch on error reporting? In configuration.php set ``public $debug = ;`` to 1 or true.
Could you check if Joomla's default authentication plugins are enabled?

Comment: @pe7er: How can I check whether Joomla's default authentication plugins are enabled without being able to log in?  Your question may be moot, given the New Information I just added to the original post.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, folks, for your help.  The hosting company is going to restore my account to a time before this foul-up.  Let's not spend any more time on this issue.

Comment: @GaryTrachier with a tool like phpmyadmin you can manage a mysql database. In the ``#__extensions`` table you can see which extensions (like plugins) are ``enabled``.

Comment: Thanks, folks, for all of your comments and questions.  Given the age of Joomla  3x, I rebuilt the entire site from scratch using the latest version of J.  This question is no longer relevant.